# C++ No instance of the constructor matches the argument list?

Tags: c++

I am learning class inheritance, and I am struggling to figure out a small problem. I have two classes

```
class OrderList {
private:
    std::vector<AbstractClass*> elements;


public:
    OrderList(const std::vector<AbstractClass*>& list){
    //  for (auto &i : list)
    //      elements.push_back(i);
    }

    OrderList(const OrderList& ol);

    OrderList& operator=(const OrderList&);

    virtual ~OrderList(){};


};

class DerivedOrderList : public OrderList {
    DerivedOrderList(std::vector<AbstractClass*>& list) : OrderList(list){}

    DerivedOrderList(const DerivedOrderList&);

    DerivedOrderList& operator=(const DerivedOrderList&);

    virtual ~DerivedOrderList(){};
};
```

Then, my main function calls on DerivedOrderList as such:

```
DerivedOrderList myOrderList = DerivedOrderList(myVector);
```

I am getting an error: No instance of constructor "DerivedOrderList::DerivedOrderList" that matches the arguments

What might be causing this?

Comment: What is the type of `myVector`?

Comment: It is a class derived from abstract class.

Comment: So the constructor pulls in vector<AbstractClass*>, where myVector is defined as vector<DerivedClass*> myVector

Comment: Providing complete, buildable code would help

Comment: `vector<AbstractClass*>` is not the same as `vector<DerivedClass*>`.  `myVector` needs to be a `vector<AbstractClass*>` or be implicitly convertible to a `vector<AbstractClass*>`

Comment: @NathanOliver, it seems that your solution fixed the problem I was having. Thanks to everyone who chimed in as well.

Answer (score 3):

Constructor in DerivedOrderList needs to be public.

Edit: Also see NathanOliver's comment and Rob K's answer regarding type of myVector.

Answer (score 3):

`OrderList(const std::vector<AbstractClass*>& list)` takes a const reference.

`DerivedOrderList(std::vector<AbstractClass*>& list)` takes a mutable reference. Change it to `DerivedOrderList(const std::vector<AbstractClass*>& list)`

Also, I'd recommend `typdef`ing your `vector<AbstractClass*>` somewhere. You use it in a lot of places, so **Don't Repeat Yourself**.

ETA: Also this `DerivedOrderList myOrderList = DerivedOrderList(myVector);` should be `DerivedOrderList myOrderList( myVector );` This is not Java or C#.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<AbstractClass*>` is not the same as `std::vector<DerivedClass*>`. The compiler creates a completely different class for each separate template implementation.

Why don't you just provide overloaded constructors `DerivedOrderList::DerivedOrderList(std::vector<DerivedClass*>&)` and `OrderList::OrderList(std::vector<DerivedClass*>&)`?